# Spanish firefox showing wrong translation

Tags: firefox, cakephp-1.3, language-translation

Our Cake 1.3 php site is coded with English as the default language. On the front page we have a Spanish and Brazillian flag which is used to translate the site into the desired language via the use of .po files. When the flags are sued there is no problem with translations.

However we have found that when we use a Spanish version of Firefox to look directly at the site we see the brazilian text! I would have expected to see the English text or maybe even the browsers attempt to translate into Spanish.

Our Locale folder is structured as follows:

Locale
      Por
         LC_MESSAGES
                    default.po
      Spa
         LC_MESSAGES
                    default.po

Aprt from the obvious error of Spanish visitors to the site seeing Portugese this also leads to any sign ups that are done to be registered as an English sign up which is causing us a real head ache in the admin.

Is the Spanish firefox just picking the first translation file it sees? If so how do we stop this and either get it to use the correct version or, as I suspect it should be doing, show the english text thus making it obvious to press the Spanish flag.

Any help or advise would be appreciated.

Comment: Just had confirmation from a persona living in Spain that FF is showing the site translated into Spanish but by the browser, so thats ok but I'd still like to know why the Spanish browser on and English machine manages to pick up the Portugese text from our .po file?